# SQL sort a column(varchar(255)) with numeric sort with alphanumeric data

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am using SQL server(MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64)). I want to sort data like this.

```
DocTyp-2649
DocTyp-2650
DocTyp-2651
DocTyp-2652
DocTyp-26036
DocTyp-26037
DocTyp-26038
```

my query is

```
SELECT doc_unique_id FROM docs ORDER BY doc_unique_id ASC
```

my result is

```
DocTyp-26036
DocTyp-26037
DocTyp-26038
DocTyp-2649
DocTyp-2650
DocTyp-2651
DocTyp-2652
```

what can u do?

Comment: Prefix is not same always DocTyp-

Comment: Use SUBSTRING to split the column in two parts and sort by 1st part, length(2nd part), nd part. This avoids typecast errors when 2nd part is not always numeric

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT doc_unique_id 
FROM docs 
ORDER BY cast(replace(doc_unique_id, 'DocTyp-', '') as int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly sort the data by using `substring()`  function (SQL Server)  to get the numerical data

```
select * 
from table 
ORDER BY 
cast(substring(doc_unique_id, charindex('-', doc_unique_id)+1, len(doc_unique_id)) as int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`select doc_unique_id from docs ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(doc_unique_id, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY length(doc_unique_id), doc_unique_id ASC

Comment: Error Code: 1305
FUNCTION test.len does not exist

Comment: As you are using MySQL, you can try LENGTH instead of LEN?